# A non-null string must be provided to a text widget. 'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart': Failed assertion: line 378 pos 10: 'data != null'

Tags: flutter, dart

> A non-null string must be provided to a text widget.
> 'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart': Failed assertion: line 378
> pos 10: 'data != null'

I'm getting errors while streaming data from `firestore`.

```
child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                  stream:
                      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('user').snapshots(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (!snapshot.hasData) return CircularProgressIndicator();

                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                  return Text("Loading");
                }

                return ListView.builder(
                    //scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      DocumentSnapshot currentdoc =
                          snapshot.data!.docs[index];
                      return Container(
                        height: 300,
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        color: Colors.black,
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              currentdoc.data()['description'],
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                            ),
                            Text(
                              currentdoc.data()['name'],
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                            ),
                            Image(
                              height: 180,
                              width: 180,
                              image: NetworkImage(currentdoc.data()['url']),
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      );
                    });
              },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems that the provided varibale for `TextView` has `null` value. use this code instead:

```
Text(
                              currentdoc.data()['description']??"",
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                            ),
                            Text(
                              currentdoc.data()['name']??"",
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                            ),
```

also, I suggest to use `null safety` for your `currentdoc` as follows:

```
currentdoc?.data()...
```

Comment: @SameerAhmed happy to help. I would be grateful if you set my answer as an acceptable answer.

Comment: see this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to provide a `null` value to a `Text` widget, so you need to make sure it is not null.

You can chose to either omit the widget if the value is null, or provide a default value. To omit the widget if the value is null:

```
Column(
  children: [
    if (currentdoc.data()['description'] != null)
      Text(
        currentdoc.data()['description'],
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      ),
    if(currentdoc.data()['name'] != null)
      Text(
        currentdoc.data()['name'],
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      ),
    Image(
      height: 180,
      width: 180,
      image: NetworkImage(currentdoc.data()['url']),
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
    ),
  ],
),
```

To provide a default value:

```
Column(
  children: [
    Text(
      currentdoc.data()['description'] ?? "default description",
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
    ),
    Text(
      currentdoc.data()['name'] ?? "default name",
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
    ),
    Image(
      height: 180,
      width: 180,
      image: NetworkImage(currentdoc.data()['url']),
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
    ),
  ],
),
```

Here you can of course change `"default description"` and `"default name"` to any default value of your choice.